# Weird waves on screen

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure

I have an HP Elite computer with Nvidia GeForce GT230. The machine is connected to two monitors with VGA and DVI. The system is running ArchLinux with nvidia 340.96.

My problem is the appearance of weird colored waves on the screen after some hours work with the machine. Usually, when this happens, I restart the machine and everything is fine, again.

[image: error]

What could be the problem? Is it a hardware failure?

Comment: Try Rolling back a driver on your graphics card. Also check your Display connections to make sure they are tight.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin The problem appeared the first time 1.5 years ago and is getting worse (it happens more often). In the meantime, I tried several kernels (~3.12-4.4) and drivers (several branches of the nvidia driver, nouveau doesn't seem to work). Also, the connections are screwed together.

Comment: This could be a hardware failure (or a driver failure as suggested by @NetworkKingPin)

Comment: I have seen this before on a distro i used. And it was the PC hardware acting up. What Os are you currently running on it?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin At the moment, it is ArchLinux with kernel 4.4.1 and nvidia 340.96.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Stress_Test see if you can use any tools to get some info there are some in there that may help

Comment: Do the problems also occur when you connect it to a different PC (if so, it is the monitor which is failing). If not, check the PC and the cables.  And just to check the obvious: No mobile phone or charger just below the monitor?

Comment: @Hennes I can exclude the monitors, because I use two showing the same problem and I could create a screenshot. No devices other than headphones, mouse and keyboard attached.

Comment: All earthed the same?